# Joomla Submenu dissapeared after changing order

Tags: joomla, submenu

We are using Joomla 2.5

A client of mine has accidentally selected most of the menu and the submenus and changed the order by clicking one of the blue arrows, now the sub menu is not showing anymore.

I have tried to rebuild the menu

I have tried to clear cache (both mine and joomla)

I have tried to change the order

I have tried to go into the menu module and made sure show sub menu was configured on

Does anyone have any suggestions on how this could be fixed? Would be highly appreciated.

The website is n1golf.com and as you can see none of the menus drop down, and here is a screenshot of the ordering just in-case that might help: http://d3v9w2rcr4yc0o.cloudfront.net/uploads/stream/2013/01/35569/1d30c79df72549006fdb760569e31399.jpg

Kind regards

Comment: unless you have a backup of the database when the menu items were in the correct order, then you won't be able to get them back to their original position. You position them back manually. In future, take regular backups of your site.

Comment: Hi Lodder, thanks for your response. Although as you can see in the screenshot there are links below which are meant to create a sub menu am I right? So they are positioned correctly as far as I can see?

Comment: Check the trash, they may be trashed but not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the drop down is achieved with jQuery or CSS and to enable it you specify an extra CSS Class in the menu module.  Check if there is one, then see your template's documentation to make sure it's the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function golf-tuition:38
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Window] is not a function s5_flex_menu.js:79
```

You can see that there are a couple of errors in the chrome debug console. As you have both jquery and mootools on your page - so I'd suggest there may be some kind of jquery/mootools conflict going on. Although I'm not sure why it would only have been triggered now!

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234445/need-help-resolving-what-appears-to-be-a-jquery-mootools-conflict/13234752#13234752) on how to resolve it - but to sum it up:

disable the $ alias for jQuery completely as soon as you call the jquery library using

```
// Disable the $ global alias completely
jQuery.noConflict();
```

And then for jQuery scripts use

```
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias to jQuery
... here is your jQuery specific code ...

})(jQuery);
```

To be safe I'd also do the same sort of thing to your mootools scripts:

```
(function($){

// set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias 
// to Mootools document.id
... here is your Mootools specific code ...

})(document.id);
```

The fact you haven't had these issues before means I can't be sure about whether this is a jQuery/mootools conflict or not - but often errors with the `$` symbol do suggest there is such a conflict!