# Joomla 3.3 Beta - Loading jQuery in normal mode

Tags: jquery, joomla

As described in docs.joomla.org [(this page)](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aJavascript_Frameworks) ,to load jQuery library in normal mode (i.e. not in no-conflict mode) we should use this line of code:

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', false);
```

I used this code in my template, but it still loads jQuery in no-conflict mode.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pilot/media/jui/js/jquery.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pilot/media/jui/js/jquery-noconflict.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pilot/media/jui/js/jquery-migrate.min.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pilot/media/system/js/caption.js">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pilot/media/jui/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Any idea what's happening?

Comment: It might be possible that another extension is loading jQuery in noConflict mode.

Comment: @Lodder Yes. I'd better use George Wilson's solution mentioned below. Thanks for your care.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if anything else calls jQuery in no-conflict mode - whether Joomla core for it's scripts or any third party extension then no conflict is loaded.

I've submitted a bug request to Joomla for it - but to be honest there's no reason why you shouldn't make sure you're scripts work in no conflict (especially as Joomla still loads mootools in places which screws up the `$` alias - see [Need help resolving what appears to be a jQuery/MooTools conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13234445/need-help-resolving-what-appears-to-be-a-jquery-mootools-conflict/13234752#13234752) for more info). Just wrap any jQuery code up with

```
(function($){

// Set a local $ variable only available in this block as an alias to jQuery
... Here is your jQuery specific code ...

})(jQuery);
```

and you're good to go!